# From php web to wordpress conversion, href changes only in URL

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html, bootstrap-4

I have converted my PHP dynamic website into WordPress. Whole design is perfect. But unfortunately, when I click on any href link. it just changes in URL but not displaying the related linked page. Following images clarify more good:
[image: this image shows index page of website.]

When clicking on link:

```html
<li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Degree Pages">
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDegreePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-graduation-cap"></i>
        <span class="nav-link-text">Degree Management</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseDegreePages">
        <li><a href="addDegree.php">Add New Degree</a></li>
        <li><a href="viewDegrees.php">View All Degrees</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

result of clicking on

> Add New Degree
>   [image]

See URL in below image:
[image: this is dispalying. not page shown which link I clicked..]

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: looks like its working wheres the code for when you're on that page

Comment: You may be best asking on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for a good answer from the specialists :)

Comment: This type of problem can happen if you are not properly using the WordPress templating system to load new pages. I would read up on https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/